# How to add some alternative authentication with token on Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, agent, asp.net-core-identity

We have built some Asp.Net Core web API, with the authentication/authorization built on top of Asp.Net Core identy, with some JWT token exchange for our angular frontend. Basically, the users can login with username+password, this provide them a JWT with a short validity that the frontend regularly refresh. If the token is not valid anymore, the user will have to login again.
This part works great.

Now, we have to add another concept, a bit like on Azure Devop, we need to add "agent", those are not users, they will just need to be authenticated, in a slightly different way:

1. They will run on unnattended(locked) computers
2. They will be configured once and then run forever
3. Each agent should NOT be considered as a user. They should not be stored as such(or at least provide a way to distinguish them)
4. Those agent should only have some kind of token/private key to authenticate themself, that doesn't expire. This method of authentication should not be allowed to other users

So based on this:

1. Is this something that already exists, or have this pattern a name?
2. Is there a way to achieve this through Asp.Net Core identity or am I better off ?
3. Any link or lead on how to implement in parallel of an existing auth would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can add an alternative authentication scheme and add a "default forward selector" on the default scheme to change the default for the request to this other scheme based on headers etc. If the API endpoints that these clients can call are separate, you could also specify the required authentication scheme for those endpoints.

Comment: @juunas Hi! Thanks for the answer! So my understanding is that would not use identity framework at all, right? How would you generate and verify a token/private-public-key ?